# Como puedo Pasar ArrayList<File> a un servicio

Tags: java, android

Quiero pasar un ArrayList File hacia un servicio para visualizar sus datos pero no me es posible en la linea que recibe la información, el programa se detiene, este es el codigo

**Metodo para enviarlo**

```
public void SendToService(){
    Intent service=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForegroundService.class);
    if(ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING){

        AdapterService=recibidor_file; 

        service.setAction(Constantes.ACTION.DATA_ACTION);
        ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING=true;
        service.putExtra("key",AdapterService);

        startService(service);

    }
}
```

**Este es el servicio**

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int StarId){

    recibidor=(ArrayList)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("key");
    titulo=String.valueOf(recibidor);
```

}
De antemano muchas gracias, este problema me tiene la cabeza grande en donde busco hablan de `getIntent` pero no funciona dentro de un Servcio

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.a7860k.reproductor, PID: 8787
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.a7860k.reproductor.ForegroundService@384fbbd1 with Intent { act=com.example.a7860k.reproductor.action.startforeground cmp=com.example.a7860k.reproductor/.ForegroundService (has extras) }: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2911)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                  at com.example.a7860k.reproductor.ForegroundService.onStartCommand(ForegroundService.java:82)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2894)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: Que te muestra el Logcat cuando se detiene?

Comment: Espera lo edito....... ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo logre resolver,gracias Einer tuve que cambiar una pequeña cosa, primero se envia los datos desde la actividad principal de forma normal

**SentToServer**

```
 public void SendToService(){
    Intent service=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForegroundService.class);
    if(ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING){

        ArrayList<File>AdapterService=new ArrayList<>();

        AdapterService=recibidor_file;

        service.putExtra("Files",AdapterService);
        startService(service);

    }
}
```

Despues solo recibir los datos con:

```
ArrayList<File>recibidor_file=new ArrayList<>();    
recibidor_file= (ArrayList<File>) intent.getExtras().get("Files");
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta en vez de enviar un `ArrayList` de `File`, enviar las url de los archivos como string utilizando el metodo `Intent#putStringArrayListExtra` para enviarlo y para recibir el metodo `Intent#getStringArrayListExtra`.

Para enviarlo seria asi:

```
public void SendToService(){


    Intent service=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForegroundService.class);
    if(ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING){

        AdapterService=recibidor_file; 


        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for(File f : recibidor_file)
        {
          urls.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        service.setAction(Constantes.ACTION.DATA_ACTION);
        ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING=true;
        service.putStringArrayListExtra("key", urls);

        startService(service);

    }
}
```

Y para recibirlos en el servicio seria asi:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int StarId){

    ArrayList<String> filesUrls =(ArrayList)intent.getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("key");

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String fPath : filesUrls)
    {
        files.add(new File(fPath));
    }

    recibidor = files;
    }
```

Comment: Si llegan los datos como string pero en la iteracion con filesUrls para pasar los datos al nuevo Arralist File se crashea o se detiene en la linea del for

Comment: De que tipo de dato es la variable recibidor_file?

Comment: ArrayList File, pero sus datos los recibio de una interface que tambien es un ArrayList Files

Comment: Puedes mostrarme el error que muestra el logcat cuando se detiene?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: Intentemos algo. Cambia `intent.getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("key")` por `intent.getStringArrayListExtra("key")` y me dices que pasa.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza habia un daño masivo en el internet por mi sector, no funciono, el mismo error